# Proving differentiable for a function with modulus and greatest integer function

Tags: calculus

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/705810950195904613/715646581885370391/340193216739541024.png

Consider, 
For, lhd I got

$\frac{ \frac{h ( e^{ [-h] +h}  -2 }{ [-h] +h} -1}{h}$

Now, I am having difficulty simplifying this expression further , help pls

Edit: it was given that f(0) = -1

Comment: Treat $[x]$ as though it is a constant.

Comment: $f(x +h) \ne f(x)  +f(h)$ and $(x+h)(\frac {e^{[x+h]+|x+h|}-2}{[x+h]+|x+h|}- (x)(\frac {e^{[x]+|h|}-2}{[x]+|x|}\ne (h)(\frac {e^{[h]+|h|}-2}{[h]+|h|}$.  Note that if $[x+h] =[x]$ for small $h$ for *very* obvious reasons.  And $[-h] = -1$ if $0< h < 1$ and $[-h] = 0$ if $-1< h < 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n\ge 1$.

for $x\in(n,n+1)$,

$$f(x)=x\frac{e^{n+x}-2}{n+x}$$

and for $x\in (n-1,n)$,

$$f(x)=x\frac{e^{n-1+x}-2}{n-1+x}$$

$f$ is differentiable at $ (n-1,n)\cup (n,n+1) $ as a quotient of two differentiable functions But not continuous at $x=n$ because
$$f(n^+)\ne f(n^-)$$

Comment: I wanted a proof..

Comment: "I wanted a proof."  Then go to amazon.com and look to see if you can buy one.

Comment: there are somethings money cant buy :-)

Pl check edit of question I missed on small bit of information